# Need tight corner, but end up getting pinched geometry!

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface, geometry

I'm looking to create the following surface with a tight radius corner, but the only way I know how to do that is to create loop cuts close to each other, which results in pinched geometry. Anyone know how to fix this? I've linked the file below.

[Link To Blender File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k5Wpor8tW0QRZcVy7yyfcs-GI5QfSsv1/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your file is locked so no-one can download it!

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! It's unlocked now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by copying the normal vectors of non-pinchy vertices and then pasting them to the pinchy vertices and flatten them out. I needed to do this separately for every problem vertex though. I don't know a way to do it all in one fell swoop. I tried to multi-select and paste, but it ended up breaking other normals by me trying to do too many at once.

Go into Edit Mode and select a vertex that has no pinch. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> to bring up the Normals Menu, and then choose the *Copy Vectors* option. Now select a problem vertex. Go back to the same Normals menu and choose the **Paste Vectors** option. You may find that some trial and error is needed to ensure that you aren't making things worse, but in relatively short order, I had the smooth surface you see here.

[image]

There may be a more elegant solution. Anyway, hope this helps.

Comment: Really appreciate the response and the effort it took to construct and explain!!